# coining new verb using existing noun forms

Tags: synonyms

We sometimes create verbs from adjectives to describe  associated action

for example *simplify* from *simple*...

Can we also coin new verbs from nouns like:

If *destruction* is from verb *destroy*,

can *construction* be from *constroy*?

Comment: You can use English anyway you want. But your usage may or may not be taken up by other speakers.

Comment: Yesterday's [Guardian crossword](http://www.theguardian.com/crosswords/cryptic/26447/print) was themed on such "back-formations", and related word-pairs where the original bare root is so rare as to be unrecognised as a standard word. Such as **[de]molish, [un]couth, [dis]sheveled, [dis]gruntled, [un]kempt, [im]pecunious, [dis]straught**. Must be a meme going round. But it's a "game" for fluent native speakers - I wouldn't advise learners to experiment too much, since they'll just get a lot hopelessly wrong.

Answer (score 6):

[image]There's historical precedence for nouns becoming verbs.  The word access used to only be a noun.  For example:

> The police gained access to the building.

Now, due to computers, it's commonly accepted to also be a verb:

> It won't let me access the database.

See http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=access -- it attributes the first use of the word "access" as a verb to about 1962.

But of course, no individual person has control over how language evolves.

As for your example of construction, there is a verb already related to construction -- "construct".

Comment: +1 for Calvin & Hobbes. I recall that strip now you posted it here. Also, I believe Shakespeare was fond of verbing nouns and nouning verbs.

Comment: My all-time favorite Calvin & Hobbes strip. Deliciously self-referential.

Answer (score 5):

*Construction* is associated with *construct* meant as a verb. 
See: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/construct
*Construct* is much less common than *build* though. 
*Building* is also arguably more common than *construction*.

Note that *build* has a germanic origin, while *construction* has a latin origin.

Note that also *destruct* exists, but in modern English it's used only when referring to things such as self-destruct mechanisms.

Both *destroy* and *destruct* have a primary latin origin, but *destroy* comes from old French *déstruire* (nowadays the *s* has disappeared) which originally comes from latin, while *destruct* comes from actual latin (compare with Italian *distruggere*).

Note that *destruction* and *construction* in French are written in exactly the same way. The pronunciation changed a bit, as always, but English does not update the spellings to reflect it.

Also to *build* in modern French is *construire* (here the *s* didn't disappear, funny). 
So if *destroy* comes from *déstruire*, you could say that *constroy* is a legit word too. Except it isn't, because English did not absorb the French word (but the Latin one) and the word was not subjected to the same linguistic process that changed the word *déstruire* either, so the word does not exist.

As you can see, English is completeley arbitrary. All languages are subject to arbitrary changes, but English is especially flexible and arguably this is an advantage, even though it makes it difficult to spell for native speakers.